# Get month number from month name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a varchar field coming out as: MON-YYYY.

I need to extract the month number from the field.
Ex: APR 2017.

Expected output: 04

Sure, since we have only 12, I can do a substring and case, but trying to do it in one shot using the below:

```
    to_char(to_date(Period,'MON YYYY'),'MM') as Month
```

keeps running into errors -numeric found where non-numeric is expected etc.

What is wrong here? Is there any other simpler way to get "04" from APR 2017

Comment: You are doing this correctly.  Converting your string to a date, then running to_char to get the numeric value of the month.  You're error is coming from something else.  Can you provide the code around this and the actual error you are receiving?

Comment: I suspect you have string values in your column that are not in the format you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your oracle language, it seems to be in another.

Because im trying with this code:

```
select to_char(to_date('ABR 1990','MONTH yyyy'), 'mm') as MONTH from dual;
```

And i get:

[image: Result]

*Note: My native language is Spanish.*

Answer (score 1):

What about the EXTRACT function?

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date(Period,'MON YYYY'),'MM') as Month
```

Comment: I get a 'missing right parenthesis' on this.  I think you kept the paren from the to_char and the to_char format when you converted it from the question.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake, left in the parenthesis from your post.

Answer (score 0):

if you need result in integer format-
Try this -

select EXTRACT(Month FROM to_date(<month_name_column>,'mon')) from <table_name>

example-
select EXTRACT(Month FROM to_date('January','mon')) from dual

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 5 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.